# Grant FullControll to the MSMQ Queues related to current Host

Tags: nservicebus

In my organization we are deploying our components using Microsoft TFS. The NServiceBus components are deployed as Windows Service by the BuildPortal.It typically creates the automated MSI packages and deploys it on the target servers. To deploy the MSI packages, the build portal uses the Service account (the Administrator/SuperUser). The NServiceBusHost will not run with the same service account, either it will use the System account or different Service account, which has restricted permission on the server and the account will not be part of the Administrator group.

In short, the Host /install command runs with different account than the actual NServiceBusHost execution. During the install, all the required queues are created by the installer (by using NServiceBus.Integration profile). Now, the problem is, since the queue created by different account than the original service account, it throws the following error.

```
Message:Could not create queue error@xxxxxxx01 or check its existence. Processing will still continue. 
NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities.CreateQueueIfNecessary(:0) 
System.Messaging.MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Access to Message Queuing system is denied. 
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.SetPermissions(AccessControlList dacl) 
at NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities.SetPermissionsForQueue(String queue, String account) 
at NServiceBus.Utils.MsmqUtilities.CreateQueueIfNecessary(Address address, String account)
```

To resolve the above error, we tried to use the INeedToInstallSomething. But, there are no proper documentation/sample on how to use or what to use inside the Install() method. When we call the **Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn().Install()** the installer is not creating the queues as expected. All we wanted is, to get the list of dependent queues of current installer & set the permission something like this >> ***messageQueue.SetPermissions(serviceAccount, MessageQueueAccessRights.FullControl)***

Is this possible to get all the dependent queues for the current Host and assign the permission during the Host install only.

NOTE:

- We dont want to move this logic outside of the host for now. Yes,
  having a simple PSS may help to reslove this issue.
- We have to use the restricted account to run the Host which can't be a Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I would try either `INeedToInstallInfrastructure<T>` and set the permissions there, or this may be like the perf counters which uses `IWantToRunBeforeConfigurationIsFinalized`.  You may need the latter and I'm not sure what order if any is used for `INeedToInstallInfrastructure<T>`.

Comment: It looks like NSB already fixed the permission issue. [https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/358](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/issues/358). But, still I am able to see the trace of error message while the Components start-up. It is unable to validate the queue existance. But, NSB is keep on executing though it logs this error. As of now we are looking good.